# Constraining Values with ComboBoxes in CMake (cmake-gui)

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui, cmake-language

I encountered CMake project where cache entry in cmake-gui was presented as combobox. But I can't find this project. How to add cache entry to CMakeLists.txt with values constrained with combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the a variable to a default value and add it to the cache.

```
set(COLOR_MODE "always" CACHE STRING "Should we use colors")
```

Then you can set the property for the variable to the list of values you want to appear in the combobox.

```
set_property(CACHE COLOR_MODE PROPERTY STRINGS always auto never)
```